# Sqlite Copied issue

Tags: ios

I have created a `SQLite` file using FireFox sqliteManager and imported it to my application.
I need to copy this `SQLite` file from bundle to document directory. By using the below code, I am able to copy the `SQLite` file to document directory.

```
   fIlMan=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    data=[fIlMan contentsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"mydatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
    pAth=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localDBFile"];



NSLog(@"%.2f",(float)data.length/1024.0f/1024.0f);



if ([fIlMan fileExistsAtPath:pAth]==NO) {
    [fIlMan createFileAtPath:pAth contents:data attributes:Nil];
}
if (sqlite3_open([pAth UTF8String], &newDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"DataBase successfully Created");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"DataBase Failed to Create");

}
sqlite3_close(newDB);
```

Now if I run it in simulator its fine(nicely working). When I run this same on device, the application will terminate and show the warning as

> Terminated due to memory pressure

Guidance needed on this. Thanks.

Comment: That's cos you are copying in a really bad way.  There is no need for a single byte of that sqlite file to be loaded into your app.  Please search for a better solution, which are only seconds away...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method of the file manager so that the file isn't loaded into memory.

Also, be careful about the destination path as `[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localDBFile"]` is not a suitable way to get the `document directory`. Instead you should be using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` or `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`.

Comment: But with above code we can copy only the path and file name, but not Data  Because I am showing the error Like no such table: grid_data'   Actually I am using MBTileFile as sqlite  Please show some alternate

Comment: That copies the file from one location to another (I incorrectly used move initially, but you should use copy). If you're using `MBTileFile` then you should use the associated API, not access the file contents directly...